# Rotation issue when switching UIWindow

Tags: ios

When I'm making another window the key window the status bar does not rotate according to what the current key window's root view controller responds to should autorotate.
I created a sample project that clearly demonstrates what I'm talking about:
http://bit.ly/tFLodd

Just run the app in the simulator rotate the interface and press the switch button rotate rotate ... and switch ... etc.

Does anybody have any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: try not to add more than one window. instead add UIViewControllers and set shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: 
to    
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
or
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

Comment: The app I'm working on has a home screen like interface with a couple of "apps" in it and each app has it's own window. I ended up using multiple windows because there are some issues with split views when they become the root view controller.